# EF Core 5.0 Many-To-Many delete from nested collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

My models are like this (simplified):

```
    public class Request
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tag
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public List<Request> Requests { get; set; }
    }
```

DatabaseContext (as shown in documentation here: [Many-To-Many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)):

```
    builder.Entity<Request>()
        .HasMany(r => r.Tags)
        .WithMany(f => f.Requests)
        .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("request_tags"));
```

How do I delete element from Request.Tags collection without deleteting tag itself? Basically I need to delete entry in join table. I tried in controller something like this:

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteTag(string requestId, string tagId)
    {
        var request = await _context.Requests
                    .Include(r => r.Tags)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id.Equals(requestId));

        var itemToDelete = request.Tags.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id.Equals(tagId));
             
        request.Tags.Remove(itemToDelete);
        _context.Requests.Update(request); //AsNoTracking behaviour is enabled
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
```

And it takes no effect. I can manually delete row on join table via **_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw()** but it seems like workaround. Is there a better way?

Comment: what is FilterFlags in `request.FilterFlags.Remove(itemToDelete);` line? It that correct?

Comment: Sorry, meant request.Tags.Remove(itemToDelete). Edited code for simplicity

Comment: Does `_context.Tags.Remove(itemToDelete);` work?

Comment: It actually does work. Thanks for advice.

Comment: @mxmissile could you explain why it works this way? It is kind of contrintuitive behavior

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I think about it, I assume it is because EF requires you to be expressive by default, so you don't hurt yourself. Your code called `Update()`, which means you want to update a record, not do any deletes. It wants you to call Remove() on the record set itself.

As is change your Remove call to:

```
_context.Tags.Remove(itemToDelete);
```

Update: Just saw this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete), it might be what you are looking for, read that link, I've never tried it though:

```
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
```